# Qt Qcamera not ready

Tags: c++, macos, qt, camera, qt5

I am using Qt 5.2 and I want to keep taking pictures from camera as soon as the camera is ready. How can I know the camera is already ready for capturing cause there is always a message "Camera not ready". Any ideas?

Comment: Post some code, some details about your environment or something else, please

Comment: @KeillRandor I am using the QCamera object for handling my camera, I just wanna know if there any return value from QCamera can be used to judge the ready status of the camera? Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QCamera` has this signal:

```
void statusChanged(QCamera::Status status)
```

which has a `QCamera::Status` parameter. You can connect the signal to a slot and check if the status is `QCamera::ActiveStatus`. It indicates that the camera has been started and can produce data.